# For $p$-separable group with abelian Sylow $p$-subgroups we have $G = O_{p'pp'}(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A finite group $G$ is called $p$-separable if there exits a series of characteristic subgroups
$$
 1 = A_0 < A_1 < \ldots < A_{n-1} < A_n = G
$$
such that each factor group $A_i / A_{i-1}$ is a $p$- or a $p'$-group. See [for example here](http://planetmath.org/piseparablegroup). (for a prime a $p'$-group is a group whose order is not divided by $p$). Now denote by $O_p(G)$ the largest normal $p$-subgroup in $G$ and by $O_{p'}(G)$ the largest normal $p'$-subgroup and define characteristic subgroups $O_{p'p}(G), O_{p'pp'}(G) \le G$ by
$$
 O_{p'p}(G) / O_{p'}(G) = O_p(G / O_{p'}(G))
$$
and $O_{p'pp'}(G) / O_{p'p}(G) = O_{p'}(G/O_{pp'}(G))$.

Now consider the following statement:

> Let $G$ be $p$-separable for $p \in \pi(G)$ and $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $O_{p'p}(G)$. If $G$ has abelian Sylow $p$-subgroups, then $G = O_{p'pp'}(G)$.

Proof: If $P \le S \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ and $S$ is abelian, then $S \le C_G(P) \le O_{p'p}(G)$. $\square$

I do not get it, why does $S \le O_{p'p}(G)$ implies $G = O_{p'pp'}(G)$? In the proof a statement is used which says that under the assumptions of the statement we have $C_G(P) \le O_{p'p}(G)$.

Comment: This (i.e. $S \le O_{p'p}(G) \Rightarrow G = O_{p'pp'}(G)$) really is very easy. Think about it a bit longer!

Comment: We have $|G : S| = |G : O_{p'p}(G)||O_{p'p}(G):S|$, so $|G : O_{p'p}(G)|$ is not divisble by $p$. Hence $\overline G := G / O_{p'p}(G)$ is a $p'$-group and we have $O_{p'}(\overline G) = \overline G$. So the inverse image of $O_{p'}(\overline G)$ is $G$, but by definition $O_{p'pp'}(G)$ is this inverse image, so $O_{p'pp'}(G) = G$. I am sorry, but I was too sticked on computing and getting an overview of all these factor groups that I was totally blind for the essentials of this argument...